# How to create toggle button with icon and text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, material-components-android

What would be the best way to build a togglebutton in android like shown in the image below. I spend more time than i like to admit trying to get it right but so far it seems inpossible to get rounded background and an icon at the same time.

My Layout

```
            <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg_rounded_corners"
            android:button="@drawable/check"
```

Check

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/app_checkmark"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/app_close"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    </selector>
```

BG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/appcolor_yellow" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/appcolor_green"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

[image: button example]

What i got

[image]

Comment: I would recommend you use `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton`. It has such attributes as `app:icon`, `app:iconGravity`, `app:iconSize`,  `app:iconTint`, `app:backgroundTint`. With these you can achieve such UI as described on your picture. Yeah, it's not actually `ToggleButton` but for me it would be easier to locally track `toggled` state in your `ViewModel` or `Fragment` than trying to create proper xml for background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `MaterialButton` with `android:checkable="true"`:

```
   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:checkable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@drawable/btn_toggle_background"
        app:iconGravity="start"
        app:icon="@drawable/..."
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        ../>
```

where `btn_toggle_background` is a selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/..." />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/..." />
</selector>
```

with:

```
    button.addOnCheckedChangeListener { button, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked){
            button.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.xxx)
        } else {
            button.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.xxx)
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]